# RecyclerView reusing variables inside custom view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I'm creating a custom ExpandableTextView to use in RecyclerView.

```
class ExpandableTextView : AppCompatTextView, View.OnClickListener {

    private var isCollapsed = true
    ...
```

The custom view itself works, but when used in a RecyclerView, the expanding state is also recycled with the ViewHolder. I suspect the var `isCollapsed` is reused too. How can I make RecyclerView display the TextView and its expanding state correctly? Can I make my variables not being reused?

Please help me to find some solutions. Any answer would be of great help!

Edit: I've added [a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEkDM.gif) to clarify. When I click on the first TextView, the last one also get expanded. Sorry I cannot post image yet!

Comment: You want to be have only one expanded view at a time?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I mean first I expand the 1st TextView, then I scroll the RecyclerView to load new data. The next TextView is loaded, say the 7th one, is also expanded like the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do make the variable `isCollapsed` public so you can change it from outside

```
class ExpandableTextView : AppCompatTextView, View.OnClickListener {

    var isCollapsed = true
    ...
```

Your adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder :YourViewHolder, position:Int) {
    viewHolder.expandleTextView.isCollapsed = true
// Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Btw `isCollapsed ` can be set to true to make those TextView collapsed by default

Comment: Yep I changed it.